# Returning integer values from RadioButton in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I created some radio buttons in Shiny; however, I am wondering if there is a way to have the returned value be an integer, and not character.

Wanting integers came up in the context of a RadioButton being used to select gender.

When I do:

```
radioButtons(inputId="gender", "Gender", choices = list("combined" = 0, "male" = 1, "female" = 2)
```

I find that

```
print(str((input$gender)))
```

gives me

```
chr "0"
```

I know I can change this within  the server:

```
gender <- as.integer(input$gender)
```

but I'm trying hard to clean up that code by cutting lines down.

Is there any way I change the output type within the UI?

Answer (score 2):

The documentation of the argument 'choices' of the function `radioButtons()` says 'The values should be strings; other types (such as logicals and numbers) will be coerced to strings.' If you use the arguments `choiceNames` and `choiceValues` instead of `choices`,  `normalizeChoicesArgs()` within `radioButtons()` will once again coerce the values to character (which is true for other inputs like `checkboxGroupInput()` as well).

Since you define a `list` in your `choices` that will always return either `"0"`, `"1"`, or `"2"`, it is safe to coerce the values to a numeric data type in the server function of the shiny app.